# Getting error using laravel4 artisan command in cron job

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron

I have configured the task

```
/var/chroot/home/content/23/3916823/html/crc1/artisan pending approvals
```

in cron job manager of my server control panel **godady account**. After cron ran I got the error

```
/bin/sh: /var/chroot/home/content/23/3916823/html/crc1/artisan: Permission denied
```

in error mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the same command with sudo.

```
sudo /var/chroot/home/content/23/3916823/html/crc1/artisan pending approvals
```